# OpenGL stops rendering, possibly after an update

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw

I am working on a small OpenGL project using the GLFW library. Everything was fine until from one day, I can't get it to render anything except the background. So I loaded up an older version, which I am **sure** worked just fine and the same thing happens. I then went back in time and every version I tried did the same thing.

You can change the glClearColor() and this color is used, but thats the only thing you see. So I tried to strip the project down until I ended with a very basic program (a hard-coded colored cube) which still doesn't render anything.

I think the possible causes may have to do something with driver updates or me downloading newer versions of libraries, but I don't think that could have such a massive effect, given that the code worked just fine previously.

I am running 64-bit Windows 7 on GIGABYTE B75M-D3H motherboard with Intel Core i5-3350P CPU and Radeon HD 7750 graphics(Currently Catalyst 14.12, have had some updates since the problem first appeared though). I use mingw-w64 as my compiler of choice with posix threads and sjlj exceptions. I tried it on a different machine (Dell Inspiron with Windows 8.1) and got the same results.

I am using GLFW, GLEW and GLM.

The original project: https://github.com/GenaBitu/OpenStrategia

A stripped-down version: https://gist.github.com/GenaBitu/852dc4c4db6d72c945d1 (Quite messy, still not working)

Can a driver update cause this? Am I stupid and forgot something which suddenly broke the whole program?

Comment: You should strip down the code even more and include it in the question. Links to code on other sites do not work well with the SO format. Then again, this same problem has been answered many times, so there's probably not much general value. You're using a core profile context, but your code is not compatible with the core profile. The core profile requires the use of VAOs (Vertex Array Objects).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was using the Core OpenGL profile, which requires you to use Vertex Array Objects, which I didn't. Up until ~February, the graphics didn't mind, but after a certain driver update, it refused to render the object (Which I believe is the correct behaviour).